# What's the English for Chinese word "敏感词"？

Tags: translation

The Chinese word "敏感词" is translated into "sensitive words" somewhere, but I think it's not exact. What's the exact expression in English?

In Chinese, "敏感词" is the word which is not allowed to be displayed on the website or when you search it by search engine you got nothing but the warnning that it is a "敏感词" related to politics or porn etc... according to the local laws.

Comment: Can you explain what the Chinese expression *means*? Can you provide an English  sentence where you would use this word/expression?

Comment: In Chinese, "敏感词" is the word which is not allowed to be displayed on the website or when you search it by search engine you got nothing but the warnning that it is a "敏感词" related to politics or porn etc... according to the local laws. @Mari-LouA

Comment: Wordfilter seems to be the right choice here. here is the internet reference https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wordfilter

Comment: Wordfilter is a filter to filter "敏感词"，but I want the English expression of "敏感词"。@Nitika

Comment: They would probably be called **censored words** by most English speakers. The Chinese phrase is a euphemism that is also not uncommon in English (‘sensitive content’ can refer to anything deemed inappropriate for any reason), and it is probably what a comparably censored English service would write as well. Since Chinese doesn’t really have a word that matches _censor_ properly (审查 and 检查 both focus on the examination of content, rather than its suppression or removal), the more straightforward English wording doesn’t have an obvious Chinese counterpart.

Comment: Informally you could call it a **touchy subject**.

Comment: I accept "censored words" for "敏感词". Thank @JanusBahsJacquet for detailed answering.

Comment: @Lessen As I said, most English speakers would probably **call** them censored words. That doesn’t necessarily mean that’s a good translation of 敏感词, since the Chinese version is a euphemism and the English one isn’t; the English is more equivalent to 经过审查的词. _Sensitive content_ (or _sensitive words_, but that sounds less natural) is probably a better translation of the Chinese phrase as it is, but which is more appropriate in a given context depends on what context the phrase is being used in. On a Google search page, _censored words_ would never be used, but the person searching may use it.

Comment: All of which points back to the fact that *sensitive* ***does*** seem to be the correct translation. (A *literal* translation often conveys the wrong meaning.)